# How can a derived class pointer to a base class object call methods of the derived class?

Tags: c++, derived-class

```
class BaseClass{

public:
    int a;
    char buf[250];

    void abcd(){
        cout<<"hello base from abcd";
    }

    virtual void defg(){
        cout<<"hellow base from defg";
    }
};

class DerivedClass: public BaseClass{

public :
    int b;
    char bufb[255];

    void bcde(){
        cout<<"hello base from bcde";
    }

    virtual void defg(){
        cout<<"hellow base from defg";
    }
};

int main(){

    BaseClass* bas=new BaseClass();
    DerivedClass* der;

    der=static_cast<DerivedClass*>(bas);
    cout<<"address of der ="<<der <<"   base= "<<bas<<endl;
    der->bcde();
    cout<<endl<<"Base size:"<< sizeof(*bas)<<"  Derived size:"<<sizeof(*der)<<endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

How can derived class pointer to base class object can call methods of derived class. WHY and HOW ?
As base class object created in memory is of only size of base class, how could it contains derived class methods. and it successfully got called.

OutPut:==>

address of der =002585A8        base= 002585A8

hello base from bcde

Base size:260   Derived size:520

Comment: It is not the pointer that calls these methods. It is *you* who calls these methods. And what you are doing is illegal in C++. And no, did did not call it "successfully", as you seem to believe, you simply performed an illegal action which sorta-kinda "worked" by accident.

Comment: How could it not? You tricked it into thinking it was pointing to a Derived type object with your cast.

Comment: freely to ask, actually i have got confused a bit about this casting operation and the derived class method pointer added to object which is not present in instance created previously as it is of base. Excuse me if i am asking some silly thing, but please make clear me to the concept.

even though i tricked him, how does casted object got the derived class method pointer in it? is it added by compiler due to  static_cast operator?

Comment: "... got the derived class method pointer in it"? What "method pointer" are you talking about? Object don't have method pointers in them for non-virtual methods. What would be the point of that anyway? Method pointers do exist for virtual methods, but even those are stored indirectly, in an external table.

Comment: yes, i have got confused, got all the thing now in my plate...
object dont have method pointers in them and virtual method pointers are stored in VTable whose pointer(vptr) is stored in object.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler bound the non-virtual method bcde based purely on the type information. As the method doesn't refer to the object contents, memory layout did not come into play.

Comment: ok, that means because of this bounding size of object is changed to 520 which is initially 260. am i right ?

Comment: No - the compiler is doing everything based on what is *supposed* to be behind those pointers.  The fact you lied to the compiler with that cast just means it is confused.  As Cheers... says, you are in the realm of undefined behaviour.

Comment: freely to ask, actually i have got confused a bit about this casting operation and the derived class method pointer added to object which is not present in instance created previously as it is of base. Excuse me if i am asking some silly thing, but please make clear me to the concept.

Comment: Implementation wise, there is no need for a method pointer in the derived class because the method is not virtual.  If it were virtual there would be some structure to dynamically look up the method at run time.  The exact nature of the structure is up to the compiler/runtime implementation.

Comment: Got your point, size of object just include sum of data member sizes. not any pointer for methods(non virtual) in it.

Got clearer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

By casting the pointer to `DerivedClass*`, when the most derived object is of type `BaseClass`, and by then using that pointer to access `DerivedClass` stuff, you have **Undefined Behavior**, UB. One possible effect of UB is that what one mistakenly believed would happen, happens. Other possibilities include crashes, hangs and weird results.

In practice, since `DerivedClass::bcde()` doesn't access any data in the instance, and doesn't call any virtual function, the only possible crash cause would be explicit checking inserted by the compiler.

I do not know of any compiler that adds such checking, but the compiler is free to do so, and generally it's free to just assume that UB will not happen.

Comment: I thought it will give the invalid memory access exception. why not ?

Comment: well first of all it's not accessing any invalid memory. but let's say you added some use of instance variables (data members). then you would be dealing with arbitrary memory contents, in the standard called *indeterminate values*. so you could at least see some very ungood results. but checking of validity is at best page-based, with each memory page of say 4K or so, or larger. at that granularity most likely the invalid memory access would still be in a valid page, and so not detected as invalied.

Comment: great, i got the memory validity (due to whole page is validated). but what about method pointer in casted object ? how does it came ?

Comment: All methods (excluding virtual) don't belong to class after compilation. It's a general functions, which takes pointer to object in first argument. And if access to memory don't uses inside method pointer value doesn't matter. For example `MyClass *ptr = NULL; ptr->func();` is valid code. P.S. feel free to review my English:)

Comment: @Kastaneda: yes you can think that way as an explanation of what actually happens. but it's still formally UB. and so with some other compiler, e.g. one that emits checks, or one that detects the UB at compile time and uses it to "optimize", the program might crash or hang or do nothing or whatever. one has to be very careful to differentiate betweeen (1) valid in the sense of standard, and (2) works with a given compiler and options etc. because the compiler does what one reasonably expects it to.

Comment: I think it's well worth the time to re-read [Raymond Chen's blog post about x64 "not-a-thing" register values](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx), “if you have a register whose value is NaT and you so much as breathe on it the wrong way (for example, try to save its value to memory), the processor will raise a STATUS_REG_NAT_CONSUMPTION exception”

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistakes in the output messages

```
class DerivedClass: public BaseClass{

public :
    int b;
    char bufb[255];

    void bcde(){
        cout<<"hello base from bcde";
    }

    virtual void defg(){
        cout<<"hellow base from defg";
    }
};
```

DerivedClass should print "hello **der** from bcde", not "hello **base** from bdce". And actually your code prints message from DerivedClass.